# posting to php using $.ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, post

I am using $.ajax jquery method, to post num to php, but im not sure how to pick it up on the php side, this is what i have, gives an undefined index error on num so its not finding it.

I would like to know how to pick the variable up in php after posting it there via the $.ajax method.

```
<?php 

$lol =  $_POST['num'];

echo " $lol";


?>
```

this is the JS:

```
<script>
 var num = 1;
                    function ajax_post(){ 
$.ajax('javas.php', {
success: function(response) {
      $(".status").html(response);
}, 
data: "num=" + (++num)
});
}

function ajax_posta(){
$.ajax('javas.php', {
success: function(response) {
      $(".status").html(response);
}, 
data: "num=" + (--num)
});
}

$(document).ready(function() {
$('.eventer > .button').click(function () {
    ajax_post();
});
alert("lol");
});


</script>
```

This JS is carried out on click of a button

Comment: Umm. Like that… Your problem must be with the JS you are using.

Comment: I think you should add the js code as well. You php code looks fine besides the fact that you do not need the quotes around the @lol variable when echo-ing.

Comment: im gnna add the jquery into my question

Comment: well, you are looking for a key "num" in the post array. So this means you should a) use the `post` method (as opposed to `get`) and b) have a field in there that is called 'num'. If you'd show your ajax call We might be able to tell if this is what you are doing, and therefore if this mighr be rigth.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) uses GET by default, so either use `$_GET` instead of `$_POST` in your PHP script, set the `type` setting in your `$.ajax()` call to `"post"`, or use `$.post()` (which uses `$.ajax` internally).

Answer (score 0):

Rather than `$.ajax` I recommend using `$.post` instead.